# Changing raster value based on point feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I am working on some landslide modeling.

Within ArcMap I have a raster layer, representing the area of the county I am working in, and a point layer that shows landslide locations. I reclassified the county raster so all cells have a value of "0".

Is there a native GIS tool or script that allows me to change the value of the county raster based on landslide point location?

Whenever a landslide point (or multiple points) are located within one sell, the value should change from "0" to "1".

My goal is to have a county raster layer where cells with the presence of landslides are coded "1" and absence "0".

I guess I could also convert the point feature to raster and then use some form of map algebra?! Not sure about the expression needed though.

So far I was only able to find the "extract values to points" tool which accomplishes pretty much the opposite.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add an attribute of 1 to the points and use this for step 2.
2. [Convert the points to raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/point-to-raster.htm) using the same extent (environment settings > extent> Raster 1 as extent) and same resolution (environment settings > resolution > Raster 1 as resolution) and set the snap raster as well (environment settings > extent> Raster 1 as snap raster). Be sure to use mean as cell assignment to convert the points (not sum).
3. Set the NoData values to 0 using a simple [reclass](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm).
4. Now you can simply use addition. In spatial analyst use Plus to add the two raster together.

Raster 1 (all zeros)
Raster 2 (1 = landslide and rest 0).

R1 + R2 = want you want.